# Send html notification to everyone in user table (phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, notifications

I'm working on creating my own forum as a project. Users can register and then post messages asking for computer help that other users can see. I want to notify all the registered users once a new message is posted. The forum is done with simple phpmyadmin.

A notication such as this:

```
//Someone responds to a post
Notification.requestPermission();

 var data = {
    msg: "Someone responded to your message!", 
    core: "Click here to check it out."
    }

 var e = new Notification("Computer help", {
    body: data.msg + "\n" + data.core,
    icon: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/456184176090169344/HNPOSKyp.png",
    tag: "ONE TIME"
    });

e.onclick = function(){
    location.href = "https://google.com";
    }
```

It asks for permission to send a notification first, if permission isn't already granted.

My question is:
How do I send that notification to every user in the user table except for the one who posts the message. I know it'd be required for the other users to be logged in. But is it still even at all possible with phpmyadmin that stores the users and messages information?

EDIT:
Below is the code I use to output all the users in the table that are not equal to the current user. I now am working on how use the $query to send everyone the above notification.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) 
{
 header("Location: index2.php");
}

$query = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id != ".$_SESSION['userSession']); //selects all users except the one logged in and stores them into $query
$userRow=$query->fetch_array();

error_reporting(0);

if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["user_id"]. " - Name: ". $row["email"]. "<br>"; //outputs all the users in the 'users' table that's not logged in
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$MySQLi_CON->close();

?>
```

Comment: I assume you have user tables you would query your user tables to get users ID's except for the current user, from user id's you will be able to get their emails and then send the notifications, lets say for eg the current user that is logged in their id is for we would do something like :SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT id = 4;

Comment: Yeah, there's a user table I have to query. But it's not a mail that I want to use as means to send a notifcation. I want to use the html5 notification api in order to do so - like the one I wrote it in my question. I want to have that notification pop up for every user logged in immediately. How do I go about that?

Comment: same logic as above, you look who posted(you have that already)  the message/post then store the post on notifications table, with the posters id then send it to all users that do not match the user id on the notifcation tables.

eg of not tables (not_ID,user_ID,permission). Then you will be able to query both tables using the ids

Comment: I'm not sure if I explain clear but I have the logic to do it

Comment: I'm trying to understand it, I'm having trouble with it I guess. You're saying it's like "check to see who DIDNT post the message - SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT id = "$_POST[id]"" but then store the notifications in their own table? I haven't made a table for them yet because I didn't know there's the need to.

Comment: I think you should store the notifications for future reference... basically what I'm trying to say is that you have the ID of the current user that is logged in what you should do is that when user 4 post a message go fetch all your users from the users tables except for user 4 and notify the other users.

Comment: I have done almost exactly what you said. I have added the code into my question. Whenever the current user is logged in, all the other users in the table are selected from the query. I now only need to send those notifications to the users by means i'm still trying to work out :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125166/discussion-between-masivuye-cokile-and-zhyohzhy).